# custom fonts are not working in ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, truetype, custom-font

I added the .otf files to the project then imported them in `index.js`

```
import "./assets/fonts/Averta-Bold.otf";
import "./assets/fonts/Averta-Light.otf";
import "./assets/fonts/Averta-Regular.otf";
import "./assets/fonts/Averta-Semibold.otf";
```

Then in `index.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "AvertaBold";
  src: local("AvertaBold"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Averta-Bold.otf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "AvertaLight";
  src: local("AvertaLight"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Averta-Light.otf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "AvertaRegular";
  src: local("AvertaRegular"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Averta-Regular.otf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "AvertaSemiBold";
  src: local("AvertaSemiBold"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Averta-Semibold.otf") format("truetype");
}
```

next used for ui element using inline css.

```
<TextField
              sx={{
                marginTop: 4,
                fontFamily: "AvertaRegular",
              }}
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="username"
              label="WITSML username"
              name="username"
              autoComplete="username"
              autoFocus
            />
```

[image]

But no change in text of Textfield, it is still same as before.

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but otf is opentype, not truetype.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: Did you import it inside public/index.html? 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fonts.css" /> . Might need to change the path to your fonts